# Is it allowed to hide iAds even when they are available?

Tags: ios, iad

I need to hide iAds depending on certain conditions, regardless their availability. So, I was wondering if my app would be rejected in the case where I hide the iAd, even when there's an iAd being displayed.

Comment: There is no requirement to display the ad banner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iAds will not work if their alpha is set to anything other than 1, so you could simply use this code to turn them off:

```
    ADBannerView *banner;
    [banner setAlpha:0];
```

This is how you would remove ads in apps, too, so your app will not get rejected for doing this - again, iAds do NOT display if the alpha is set to anything other than 1, so you can't hide an iAd and have it be displayed at the same time - pretty much, when you hide an iAd it is about the equivalent to the user not having any internet connection, and the iAd being hidden.